# Iterate using previous rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How could I create a col2 using an iterative type of rule?

`col2 = col1 + 0.1(col2's previous value). If there is no previous value (here in 20 Dec 2019), then col2 should equal col1`

```
df
  date      col1   
2019-12-20   10      
2019-12-27   3       
2020-01-03   7
```

Expected Output

```
  date      col1  col2  
2019-12-20   10     10   (no previous value, so equal col1)
2019-12-27   3      4    (3+0.1*10)
2020-01-03   7      7.4  (7+0.1*4)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `np.cumsum` *(inspired by the formula of @MustafaAydın)*

```
p = 0.1 ** np.arange(len(df)-1, -1, -1)
df['col2'] = np.cumsum(p * df['col1']) / p
```

```
>>> df
         date  col1  col2
0  2019-12-20    10  10.0
1  2019-12-27     3   4.0
2  2020-01-03     7   7.4
```

Comment: 'Shift' cannot be used here as we don't use the previous value from series, but previous value from the iteration.

Comment: @Arkadiusz, you're right. I don't pay attention :-(. I fixed my answer, I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 3):

With some math, we have:

```
col2_{n} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} col1_{j} * 0.1^{n-j}
```

This can be implemented with `expanding.agg`:

```
df["col2"] = (df.col1
                .expanding()
                .agg(lambda win: (0.1 ** np.arange(win.size) * win[::-1]).sum()))
```

where `win` is the ever expanding window that is passed and `n` in the formula above is its size, i.e., `win.size` and `col1_{j}` will be its elements,

to get

```
         date  col1  col2
0  2019-12-20    10  10.0
1  2019-12-27     3   4.0
2  2020-01-03     7   7.4
```

Comment: I used your formula to fix my answer. ty. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a new list, and iterate over col1 using a for loop of col1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 10, 1: 3, 2: 7}})
col2 = []
for x in df.col1:
        if not len(col2):
            col2.append(x)
        else:
            col2.append(x+0.1*col2[-1])
df['col2'] = col2
```

There's likely other ways using `df.shift()`